# How to add a logo and website name over a slider

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

I want to add my website logo and title on a slider. I have built the website on WordPress using Elementor. I have tried to do it using Elementor but I couldn't find any way.

Maybe it can be fixed using some code. Looking for someone who can help me with that.

Please have a look at the website, so you can understand better.

https://test.lifestylerules.online/

Comment: in CSS, you can start with this: `.elementor-element-0aed915 { position: absolute; width: 100%; z-index: 9; background: rgba(0,0,0,0); }`

Comment: resulting effect: https://i.ibb.co/rxnkqTH/Peek-05-04-2022-15-19.gif